# Do I use IS or ARE in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

"John Smith and all of us at ABC Corp ARE proud to support..." or "John Smith and all of us at ABC Corp IS proud to support..."

Answer (score 0):

You have a compound subject.  John Smith and ABC Corp make two, which is plural, so you would use  **are** as the verb.  Your plural verb now agrees with your plural subject.